# My Xamarin iOS App crashes after 24 hours

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Im a high school student and I've been building this iOS app in Xamarin. I use Xcode as the visual editor and Xamarin C# for all the code. My app crashes after 24 hours. It builds and runs fine but after a day, it won't open at all on my iPhone 5s. It's odd because I have the indie subscription for iOS. I don't however have the Android subscription. It shouldn't matter because I am not even using Android. I do have some Xamarin.Forms projects that are in my Xamarin Dashboard, but I am not using Forms, or even Android, in the app I'm having issues with. Thank you for reading and all comments are appreciated!

Comment: If it's crashing after a certain amount of time a memory leak is a likely cause.  You can use [Insights](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/insights/application/) to capture crash data that may help you diagnose it further.